# Flask syntax f-string with single quotation mark

Tags: python, f-string

In a Flask tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYWiDiIUxQc&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=4
There is a syntax I want to understand

`return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.dateposted}')"`

Can someone decompose this line for me?

1. f string means to return the result of `Post()` in a string
2. `'{self.title}'` is an argument that is a string, because with `''`
3. `{}` is used to get a variable.
4. But in the context `self.title` is ALREADY a string, why use `' '`?
   Are my explanations correct? And what does `' '` do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial he returns this value for the `__repr__` method of a class.
This method is called when `repr()` is called on the object. It's also called when you use `str()` or `print()` on the class, if a `__str__` method has not been implemented for it.

The intention of implementing a `__repr__` method is to aid debugging.
If you tried to print the object *without* defining a `__repr__`, it would print out like `<Post object at 0x00000000>`, which doesn't help!

The single-quotes are used for decoration, and they aren't really necessary.

---

See also: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)

You might also be interested in reading *Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho* as it covers these methods and gives great examples of how they might be used (in addition to a lot of other Python wisdom)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the link but this just returns a string that would break down to this.

```
return "Post('" + self.title + "', '" + self.dateposted + "')"
```

What is done with the returned string I don't know, but I assume it's evaluated somewhere else.

But all an f string does is embed variables or expressions into your string.

If the variable is not a string it converts it to a string first.

To break down your example, in an fstring, anything within the `{}` gets embedded.
Since the `'` are single quotes and outside of the curly braces, they are also part of the string.

Lets say `self.title` is equal to `"My Title"` and `self.dateposted` is equal to `"08-22-2020"`. The returned string would then result in

```
"Post('My Title', '08-22-2020')"
```

If you were to then call `exec()` with this string it would call `Post()` with 2 positional string arguments.

Comment: I don't think it is a concatenation of strings. It's calling Post function.

Comment: It is definitely not calling a `Post` function. as @VasilSyrakis mentioned `Post` is a `class` and this is returning a `__repr__` string.